# Login with linked in with socialauth-android-2.6.jar giving Crashes the app

Tags: android, social-networking

hello all i m new android person and i m trying to make an app that login with linked in but it throw exception `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.brickred.socialauth.android.SocialAuthAdapter` and crash the app. Below is my code

```
package com.example.demosocialapp;

import org.brickred.socialauth.android.DialogListener;
import org.brickred.socialauth.android.SocialAuthAdapter;
import org.brickred.socialauth.android.SocialAuthAdapter.Provider;
import org.brickred.socialauth.android.SocialAuthError;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    SocialAuthAdapter adapter;
    Button update;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button share = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        adapter = new SocialAuthAdapter(new ResponseListener());
        adapter.enable(share);

        share.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                adapter.authorize(MainActivity.this, Provider.LINKEDIN);

                }
        });
    }

    private final class ResponseListener implements DialogListener {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {

            final String providerName = values.getString(SocialAuthAdapter.PROVIDER);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, providerName + " connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(SocialAuthError error) {
            Log.d("ShareButton", "Authentication Error: " + error.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d("ShareButton", "Authentication Cancelled");
        }

        @Override
        public void onBack() {
            Log.d("Share-Button", "Dialog Closed by pressing Back Key");
        }
    }
}
```

But when i clicked on button it give error with crash : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.brickred.socialauth.SocialAuthManager

Please help me....................

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I had the same Exception with another libraries.

I think you should configure your build path:

> Right click on project - Build Path - Configure Build Path... - Order and Export

Then check your library and raise it up to the top